# Error on importing a public key 'SubtleCrypto': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence

Tags: javascript, subtlecrypto

I'm trying to import a public key into crypto.subtle and I got a cryptic (pun intended) error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'importKey' on 'SubtleCrypto': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.

Here's my key:

```
jPublicJWK = {
  "crv":"P-256",
  "key_ops":"verify",
  "kty":"EC",
  "x":"QcQI-5wvczyuzU0SWl91tdUWbG5RMYFdNrOCNHen-08",
  "y":"sYVMwVF4ZO2-u0xPMyOXff7VoOQo6kdBv0IeEcnrYno",
  "use":"sig"
}
```

And here's how I'm importing:

```
let jwkCryptoKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "jwk",
    jPublicJWK, 
    {
        name: "ECDSA",
        namedCurve: "P-256",
    },
    true,
    ["verify"]
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a `'raw'` key type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the the [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517#section-4.3), `key_ops` is an array.  "Its value is an array of key operation values."  Tricky little sentence to miss.

Since `key_ops` is optional, you can delete it all together or put it in an array:

```
jPublicJWK = {
    "crv": "P-256",
    "kty": "EC",
    "key_ops": ["verify"],
    "x": "NDeK5mTx7Tse16x4ipl1m6NYDkwLO-YBU_BUqEtOuIM",
    "y": "9Q3XDebaKId0pmrPqVTTR__UnpBn2oxqY8nAlrTw_qU",
    "use": "sig"
};
```